# ProgressDialog with LoadManager

Tags: android, android-listview, android-progressbar, android-loader

I checked questions asked in StackOverflow but couldnt make to solve my issue.
I am trying to get some data in `ListView` in asynchronous way (to not overload UI Thread) and while i get the data i want to show a `ProgressDialog`. **I am getting the data using `ContentProvider` and it loads the data successfully in `ListView`, however the `progressDialog` is not spinning, but after the list is shown with data it starts spinning and never stops (Keeps spinning).**
How can i make `ProgressDialog` spin and `dismiss()` after the `ListView` is Visible.

Here is the activity which implements `LoaderCallbacks`:

```
public class AttractionsActivity extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
private ListView attractionsListView;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_listview);


    attractionsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvCustom);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    dbHelper.open();
    populateAttractionsListView();
    dbHelper.close();
}

private void populateAttractionsListView() {
    //final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAttImage);
    //Initialize Loader
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    String[] from = {PoisContract.COLUMN_POI_MAIN_PIC, PoisContract.COLUMN_POI_NAME};
    int[] to = {R.id.ivAttImage, R.id.tvAttName};
    //Initialize CursorAdapter
    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.attractions_listview_row, null, from, to, 0);
    ViewBinder viewBinder = new ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            boolean binded = false;
            if(view != null){
                String imgName = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                int imgResId = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());
                ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(imgResId);
                binded = true;
            }
            return binded;
        }
    };
    //Set Adapter but there is no cursor right now
    attractionsListView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    //Set Binder to the adapter
    cursorAdapter.setViewBinder(viewBinder);
    //Hide ListView as there is no data returned
    attractionsListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

private Cursor getAllAttractions(){
    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();

    return resolver.query(PoisContract.CONTENT_URI, PoisContract.PROJECTION, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    progressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...", "Loading List...");

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(AttractionsActivity.this, PoisContract.CONTENT_URI, PoisContract.PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);

    progressDialog.dismiss();
    attractionsListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
    //Data is not available anymore, delete reference
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok @Luksprog thank you very  much for helping. I found the issue. The problem was in the `ContentProvier` AUTHORITY declaration. I misspelled the AUTHORITY String in one place. It took a day to figure out that stupid mistake. 
I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

> however the progressDialog is not spinning, but after the list is
>   shown with data it starts spinning

This is happening because, despite (correctly)using a Loader to load the data, you also manually query the provider on the main UI thread through the call to the `getAllAttractions()` method(in the onCreate() method) which will block the UI thread. In fact I don't know why you did that as the returned Cursor is not used at all. Remove the:

```
Cursor cursor = getAllAttractions();
```

line from your activity's `onCreate()` method to solve this issue.

> ...and never stops (Keeps spinning).

This is happening because you call dismiss on the wrong ProgressDialog reference so you don't cancel the currently showing ProgressDialog. In the onCreate() method of the Activity you create a ProgressDialog reference, however in the onCreateLoader() callback you use the show() method which creates a **new instance** of a ProgressDialog(the method is static) so when you try to dismiss it in onLoadFinished() you dismiss the previously created ProgressDialog(which isn't even showing). To solve it use:

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...", "Loading List...");
```

in the onCreateLoader() callback.

As a side note you should always call a static method of a class by using the class name and not some object reference of that class, this will make thing more clear for you and also anyone who would later read your code.

Comment: i am using `Cursor cursor = getAllAttractions();` because i need to bind `ImageView`s whose names i am getting from a locally stored DB.
in the line `viewBinder.setViewValue(image, cursor, cursor.getColumnIndex(PoisContract.COLUMN_POI_MAIN_PIC));`

Comment: @hrskrs You're doing things wrong, calling setViewValue() manually is not ok. Remove the call to getAllAttractions() and the call to setViewValue(). Th Cursor which you get from the loader already has that column(with the image) in it and the ViewBinder will make the binding automatically.

Comment: ok got it. I appreciate your help the thing is that i have also to assing the `setViewValue` view to `ImageView` of the layout. How can i do that?

Comment: @hrskrs The ImageView seems to be in the row layout of the ListView in which case, as I said, you're doing things wrong. Did you remove the lines I said above and you still have problems?

Comment: Yeah the image is in the row layout and i removed the ones you said but there is nothing shown(empty page). I think it doesnt enter inside the BindView. I updated the answer with the changes you said, Can you check it pls?

Comment: @hrskrs I've made some small changes to your ViewBinder https://gist.github.com/luksprog/f4324dbbe6229ccd82f0 .Are you sure that you get a valid name and a valid identifier of a drawable in the ViewBinder? Did you try to simply set(directly) the image in the ViewBinder to one of your drawbles (like  ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.oneOfYourDrawables);) to see if it appears?

Comment: I am getting a valid name and identifier. I logged them and im getting them. The thing is that Binding is never executed for some reason because i also tried to set the image directly from resources but there was nothing shown up, except that the `progressDialog` is shown and vanish fast.

Comment: @hrskrs Are you sure that setViewValue() doesn't get called in the ViewBinder(placing a Log statement right at the start of the setViewvalue doen't print anything?)? I don't see anything wrong with your setup. You should also remove the line where you set the visibility of the ListView to GONE, you don't really need that.

Comment: Yeah i logged again just after the `setViewValue` starts, but it doesn't get called :/ I also removed the `Visibility.GONE` same result. Loading is shown and vanished too fast and empty page is displayed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60749/discussion-between-hrskrs-and-luksprog).